# Proxmox Routed Network Configuration on Hetzner Server

Tags: networking, routing, linux-networking, proxmox, hetzner

I have a server from Hetzner with Proxmox installed

My host machine has an IP address like `xx.xx.69.241`

I requested some additional IP addresses from Hetzner and these are my additional IP addresses:

1. `xx.xx.69.242`
2. `xx.xx.69.235`
3. `xx.xx.133.14`

I have a problem with third one

Currently, My host machine Network configuration is like this:

```
auto enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet static
        address  xx.xx.69.241
        netmask  255.255.255.192
        gateway  xx.xx.69.193
        up route add -net xx.xx.69.192 netmask 255.255.255.192 gw xx.xx.69.193 dev enp0s31f6


auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address xx.xx.69.241
    netmask 255.255.255.255
    bridge_ports none
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
    pre-up brctl addbr vmbr0
    up ip route add xx.xx.69.242/32 dev vmbr0
    up ip route add xx.xx.69.235/32 dev vmbr0
    up ip route add xx.xx.133.14/32 dev vmbr0
```

And my Guest network configuration is like this for first additional IP address:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ens18
iface ens18 inet static
    address xx.xx.69.242
    netmask 255.255.255.255
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 4.2.2.4
    post-up ip route add xx.xx.69.241 dev ens18
    post-up ip route add default via xx.xx.69.241 dev ens18
    pre-down ip route del default via xx.xx.69.241 dev ens18
    pre-down ip route del xx.xx.69.241 dev ens18
```

It is working for the first and second additional IP addresses.
But the third additional IP address that is out of the range of other IP addresses is not working like the other 2 addresses.

Can anyone help me to alter these configurations to meet the requirements for the third additional IP address?

Answer (score 1):

Add a second virtual nic to each machine , with the right IP and bridge  in order to be in the same network. It's network problem you have there, not proxmox.